# 'signup' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: python, django

I want to store a username through User input but I am getting the following error:

```
`AttributeError` at /sign/ `'signup' object has no attribute 'get'`
```

Here is the relevant code I am trying to run:

*models.py*:

```
class signup(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length = 50)

    def __unicode__ (self):
        return self.username
```

*views.py*

```
def sign(request):
    username = request.POST['username']
    user = signup.objects.create(username=username)
    return render(request,'bookstore/signup.html',{'username': username})
```

*bookstore/urls.py*

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from bookstore import views
urlpatterns = patterns(' ',
    url(r'^$',views.home, name = 'home'),
    url(r'^sign/$', views.signup,name='signup'),
    url(r'^bookshow/$',views.bookshow,name='bookshow'),
    url(r'^bookshow/(?P<book_id>\d+)/$',views.bookdetails, name='bookdetails'),
)
```

## signup.html

```
 <html>


         <h2>WELCOME TO BOOKSTORE<h2>
        <h3>LOGIN TO GET IN LIBRARAY<h3>



 {% if errors %}
     <ul>
         {% for error in errors %}
         <li>{{ error }}</li>
         {% endfor %}
     </ul>
  {% endif %}


  <div>
 <form action="/sign/" method = "POST">
     {% csrf_token %}

    <input type="text" username="username" placeholder="USERNAME"/><br />
    <input type="submit" value = "signup"/>
 </form>
  </div>

 </html>
```

## error that I am getting on opening that page

```
 AttributeError at /sign/
 'signup' object has no attribute 'get'
 Request Method:    GET
 Request URL:
 Django Version:    1.6.2
 Exception Type:    AttributeError
 Exception Value:   
 'signup' object has no attribute 'get'
 Exception Location:    /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-           packages/django/middleware/clickjacking.py in process_response, line 30
 Python Executable: /usr/bin/python
 Python Version:    2.7.5
 Python Path:   
 ['/home/prakhar/pp/django/mysit',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pylint-1.1.0-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/astroid-1.0.1-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/logilab_common-0.61.0-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pep8-1.5.3-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PILcompat',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntu-sso-client',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-client',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-control-panel',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-storage-protocol']
```

Comment: Not the solution but, are you missing the last argument in the `pattern()` call?

Comment: Could you give the complete traceback please?

Comment: Does your view have code for the first time you visit sign (I.e. as a get)? I imagine you'll go so sign, enter your username and hit submit, at which point it calls the post stuff.

Comment: yes Earlier I have used get in my views.py but then deleted that

Comment: you got an answer: this piece of code `url(r'^sign/$', views.signup,name='signup')` suggests that you should have a function called signup in your views.py. And yours is called only `sign`, instead of `signup`

Comment: I corrected that as I changed my url(r'^sign/$', views.signup,name='signup') to url(r'^sign/$', views.signup,name='sign') still the same error is occuring

Answer (score 1):

There's an error in your `urls.py` file when you match the `^sign/` pattern with the `signup` view but in your views you've only defined only the view `sign`.

The error you are referring is because in your sign view you only deal with POST requests, therefore there is not way to deal with GET requests. May you can change as follows:

```python
def sign(request):
    if request.POST:
        username = request.POST['username']
        user = signup.objects.create(username=username)
        return render(request,'bookstore/signup.html',{'username': username})
    return render(request, 'bookstore/login.html')
```

where `bookstore/login.html` could be a simple HTML form with username field and in submission post to `^sign/`.

Comment: Change the input field in your template as:
    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="USERNAME"/>